# Dash Blur effect

Tags: unity-dash, panel

I am facing a probem with my Dash Blur effect. It was working normally before but when i updated Software in ubuntu 12.04, dash does not give any blur effect. If i change the wall paper then the blur effect appears. Same problem with panel.

I have tried Ubuntu Tweak, Gnome Tweak tool, Unsetting, MyUnity, etc. Nothing seems to work. Can some one help??

Comment: Have you tried [resetting Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) , it resets your Unity configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in compiz config settings manager? Have you tried that?

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

You need to go to -> Draw to unity shell option -> experimental tab and change Dash Blur option. I hope that helps.

Be careful with it though.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. I tried it too but still no effects. Actually this happened because while updating my network connection broke. And since then blur effect occurs only when I change the wallpaper. Dont know whats wrong with it?????

Comment: That sounds weird, I suppose uninstalling unity and installing it again or something like that might work but I've never tried it so I don't recommend it!